# Create a Blacklist filter in a form to avoid some words

Tags: php, javascript, input, filter

I need to create a filter to avoid some websites to be submitted to my database. I want to do this to protect the content of my website against spammers.

I have a regular form input text that is used to send a URL, I need some help to create a background action (in php maybe) that will check if this URL, that the user is trying to send, have some blacklisted words.

Comment: will never work, no matter how large the list, thousands of new ones appear daily.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to store a list of regular expressions (either in a database, or hard-coded in a file - whichever you find more convenient to work with and flexible long-term).

Then just filter the input against the the regular expressions using `preg_filter` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look into preg_match

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: What about `preg_match` will help him out?